# How do I make the staff for dynamics affect the MIDI output?

Tags: midi, lilypond

I've written a lovely<sup>[citation needed]</sup> piece of piano music using Denemo (a graphical front-end to Lilypond), consisting of a piano staff with a staff for dynamics inserted in between them.

The dynamics appear in the PDF output, but do not appear in the MIDI output. If I apply the dynamics separately to each piano staff, the dynamics appear in the MIDI output but are doubled in the PDF output.

I would like to keep the dynamics appearing once in the PDF output (using the staff for dynamics) but still get a reasonably representative MIDI output. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

I make separate score-blocks for the PDF and the MIDI. Something like the following. Note that, for the PDF, the dynamics in `\pianoCentredDynamics` are separate from the Staffs containing the notes in `\rhMusic` and `\lhMusic`. By contrast, for the MIDI for the RH, the dynamics and `\rhMusic` are put in parallel and all assigned to the Staff -- and similarly for the LH.

```
\version "2.18.2"
\include "english.ly"

\header {
} % header

\paper
{
    #(set-paper-size "a4")
}

global =
{
    \key bf \major
    \tempo 4=96
    \time 3/4
}

rhMusic =
{
    d'2. ef'4 f'g'a'bf'c''d''2.
}

pianoCentredDynamics =
{
    s2.\pp s\< s s\ff
}

lhMusic =
{
    \clef bass
    bf,2. c4 d ef f g a bf2.
}

pedalling =
{
}

% Score-block for the layout
\score
{
    \new GrandStaff 
    <<
        \new Staff = "rh" << \global \rhMusic >>
        \new Dynamics = "dynamics" \pianoCentredDynamics
        \new Staff = "lh" << \global \lhMusic >>
        \new Dynamics = "pedal" \pedalling
    >>
    \layout
    {
    }
}

% Score-block for the MIDI
\score
{
    \unfoldRepeats %\articulate
        \new PianoStaff
        <<
            % See http://lilypond.1069038.n5.nabble.com/Sustain-in-midi-output-of-Piano-Centered-Dynamics-Template-td31012.html
            \new Dynamics = "dynamics" \pianoCentredDynamics
            \new Dynamics = "pedal" \pedalling
            \new Staff = "rh" << \global \rhMusic \pianoCentredDynamics \pedalling >>
            \new Staff = "lh" << \global \lhMusic \pianoCentredDynamics \pedalling >>
        >>

    \midi
    {
        % See http://lilypond.1069038.n5.nabble.com/Sustain-in-midi-output-of-Piano-Centered-Dynamics-Template-td31012.html
        \context { 
            \type "Performer_group" 
            \name Dynamics 
            \consists "Piano_pedal_performer" 
        } 
        \context { 
            \PianoStaff 
            \accepts Dynamics 
        } 

        \context
        {
            \Staff
            \consists "Dynamic_performer"
        }
    }
} % score for MIDI
```